# Compile failed using laravel 5.4 and bootstrap-vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

tried to use the [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) for the first time but got issue upon compiling assets. When I run `npm run watch`, I got an error something like below.

```
Module parse failed: C:\projects\portfolio\node_modules\bootstrap-vue\lib\mixins\dropdown.js Unexpected token (110:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     },
|     methods: {
|         ...clickOut.methods,
|         noop() {
|             // Do nothing event handler (used in visible watch)

 @ ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/lib/mixins/index.js 2:0-38
```

**app.js**

```
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.esm';

Vue.component('b-navbar', require('./components/Navbar.vue'));
```

**Navbar.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
         <!-- navbar contents here.. -->
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import { bNavbar } from 'bootstrap-vue/lib/components'
    export default {
        components: { bNavbar }
    }
</script>
```

**Expected result**

Must display the navbar component

Comment: Just a shot in the blue: did you check your node version being >= 8.3? AFAIK "bootstrap-vue.esm" is the ES6 Module for Bootstrap-vue and the error is on the ES6 spread (...) Operator for [properties](http://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--object-rest-spread-properties) to be more specifically. I've only setup Bootstrap-vue on webpack with vue-loader/babel 2015 preset (es6 to es5 transpilation) so am not quite sure if that actually works.

Comment: @makadev, with `npm -v` it says `4.5.0`

Comment: Try `npm version`, as an example I got a pretty fresh install via brew (mac) and its `... npm: '5.3.0', ... node: '8.3.0', ...`. You may need to update^

Comment: I got `node: '6.6.0'` I'll try to update thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you try to use single BV component. In that case you need to setup your dev enviroment to be able to compile BV sources by installing babel plugin https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/ and configuring babel to include `node_modules/bootstrap-vue/lib` folder